# js simple calculator output error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple calculator ,but it doesn't work,can someone tell me where is the problem.
Thank you!

```html
<form>
  <div>First Number:</div>

  <div> <input type="number" id="num1" /></div>

  <div>Second Number:</div>

  <div> <input type="number" id="num2" /></div>

  <div><input type="button" value="Calculate Sum" onclick="sumNumbers()" /></div>
  <div>Result:</div>
  <div> <input type="number" id="result" /></div>

</form>

<script>
  function sumNumbers() {
    let num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
    let num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
    let sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = sum;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `#result` is an input. Try `('result').value = sum`

Comment: You get two DOM elements - those are objects pointing to the input elements. Check HTML documentation (Google!!!) how to get the value. Read examples on the web! Google! Read blogs! There are THOUSANDS of small examples of code that show you this kind of stuff. No need for basic private 1-on-1 programming lessons on SO.

Comment: Also `let num1= document.getElementById('num1').value;`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things

First if you want to get the input value you've to access to the `value` attribute of your input

```
document.getElementById('id').value
```

Second one, if you wanna set an input `value`, don't use `innerHTML` for this. It's only usefull when you want to update the content of a HTML element.

```js
function sumNumbers() {
    let num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    let num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    let sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = sum;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div>First Number:</div>

<div>  <input type="number" id="num1" /></div>

<div>Second Number:</div>

<div>   <input type="number" id="num2" /></div>

<div><input type="button" value="Calculate Sum" onclick="sumNumbers()"/></div>
<div>Result:</div>
<div> <input type="number" id="result" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank,you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You were not extracting the value from input,
use

```
let num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value
```

and same goes for settig the value i.e.

```
document.getElementById('result').value = sum
```

```html
<form>
  <div>First Number:</div>

  <div> <input type="number" id="num1" /></div>

  <div>Second Number:</div>

  <div> <input type="number" id="num2" /></div>

  <div><input type="button" value="Calculate Sum" onclick="sumNumbers()" /></div>
  <div>Result:</div>
  <div> <input type="number" id="result" /></div>

</form>

<script>
  function sumNumbers() {
    let num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    let num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    let sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = sum;
  }
</script>
```